How much time is recommended between two visits to India on a tourist e-visa?
I am a Norwegian citizen currently in India on a tourist e-visa.
My visa lists the following conditions:

e-Visa Validity period is 5 Years from the date of issuance of this ETA.


Activities Permitted :
Recreation/Sight-Seeing


Continuous stay in India on each entry should not exceed 90 days.


Maximum stay in India in one calendar year on an e-Tourist Visa or paper Tourist Visa or both, shall be
restricted to 180 days.


Multiple entries will be granted within the e-Visa validity period stamped on your passport.

I am approaching a continuous stay of 90 days, so I will soon have to leave India. However, how long do I have to be outside? The visa says nothing about it, so I guess in theory I could just go to Sri Lanka for one day and then come back. However, I wonder if border officials may frown upon such a "visa run" within a visa.
I tried asking the offical e-mail support for Indian e-visas how long I would have to be outside India between two visits, but they just repeated the same terms listed in the visa itself:

Dear Applicant,
The regulations regarding stay stipulation have changed for ALL
countries for eTV (1 year/5 years).
Maximum stay in India during one Calendar Year should not exceed 180
days with a 1/5 year e-tourist visa.
Continuous stay in India with each visit should not exceed 90 days
except UK, USA, CANADA, and JAPAN as these Nationals are allowed to
stay continuously for 180 days in each calendar year.
After the expiry of the existing e-visa, you may apply for a new one.
Note:- If your stipulated stay of 180 days is exhausted in a calendar
year you will be allowed to re-enter the country in the next calendar
year as per the ETA validity.
Regards e-Visa support Team

Not sure if they failed to read my question properly or just did not want to give a clear answer. I responded by asking for clarification, but still waiting for a response. It is Diwali right now, which may slow things down. I also tried to e-mail the visa section of the Indian Embassy in Norway some time back, but without getting a response.
I guess to be on the safe side I will leave India for a week or two between visits. However, it would be nice to know if anyone has any experience with this or whether any official guidance exists from Indian authorities.

IMHO in general if immigration rules are silent on elapsed time between tourist visits it’s because there is no hard and fast rule. The typical approach is to spend at least the same amount of time outside the country as in it. Returning very soon after a lengthy stay starts to look like you’re trying to live there, which could raise questions as to how you’re supporting yourself, especially as it seems that remote working for a foreign national on a tourist e-visa is not permitted

It looks like the response to your email, does answer your question. If you wish to remain in India for longer, consider applying for another visa that allows for this.

@nikhil Where does it say that? I'm fine with 180 days, I just wanna do it all during the winter so I wanna know how long of a gap I need in between two 90 day periods.

@Fiksdal the answer to that question is in the email response. You have to remember that a visa is just a document that allows you to travel and present at the point of entry. It is not a guarantee that you'll be allowed in even with a valid visa. There is no waiting period or recommended or allowed gap, if the officer at the visa counter is suspicious that you're not a bonafide tourist, then you can be denied entry. If you're able to explain to them that you are a visitor, then you'll be granted entry. Living for half an year in a country almost non stop is bound to invite scrutiny.

@nikhil All reasonable, but that is not written in the e-mail response. According to the e-mail, staying for 180 days between two 90 day periods is fine. The aditional warnings about a short gap were written by you, and not at all mentioned in the e-mail. I'm not saying your comment is wrong, I'm just saying those warnings were not in the e-mail I recieved.

@Fiksdal you're asking here because you're familiar with visa runs and how they're treated. Often times how they'll be handled is not documented and is indeed up to local policy of a border crossing, or down to how the passport police handling you is feeling that day. nikhil is trying to point out how they might handle this situation, as it's unlikely that there's a firm policy.

In general, India is strict about immigration and visas. Even us citizens have to explain things before granting entry. Being said that, legally, you are in the clear.
But you have to explain what you are doing in the country. You are a genuine tourist, who is taking an extended break from work and staying and exploring India in detail - be prepared to explain what all you did till now, what are your future plans, where are you staying, when are you leaving, why are you not visiting other Asian countries and such that. They might verify your claims and let you in.
But, if they suspect that your story is not believable, or your premise is not true, then like other country, you can be refused entry and send back to Norway. It might be a good idea to consult an immigration attorney in India. It might be very cheap for a quick consult over telephone.
PS: Srilanka may be near, but flight tickets are usually expensive and you have to pay for visa on arrival.


I am approaching a continuous stay of 90 days, so I will soon have to leave India. However, how long do I have to be outside?

In such an immigration situation, where is not clearly stated how long one must have been outside before can reenter, it should be assumed that an re-entry is at the discretion of the immigration official.

However, I wonder if border officials may frown upon such a "visa run" within a visa.

A justified assumption.

I tried asking the offical e-mail support for Indian e-visas how long I would have to be outside India between two visits, but they just repeated the same terms listed in the visa itself:

Not a great surprise, since the decision is up to the discretion of the immigration official at the point of entry.

I guess to be on the safe side I will leave India for a week or two between visits. However, it would be nice to know if anyone has any experience with this ...

This is problamatic, since in the end it is a matter of what impression you will make on the immigration official at the port of entry, during the one or two minutes of interview at the port of entry.
Nobody here can claim to know what the immigration official will deside based on the circumstances you presented to them.

How much time is recomended between two visits to India on a tourist e-visa?

Nobody can give you a realistic answer to this when the immigration rules themselfs give no answer and thus up to the discretion of the immigration official at the point of entry.
